# finding the largest attribute value in class and assigning the order

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I have an ArrayList of a custom class named 'Team'.

Every object of 'Team' has an attribute of 'setsWon' with a value assigned.

Team also has an attribute of 'rank', that is set to null. I want to find the 'Team' with the largest number of 'setsWon', and assign 'rank' to 1, and then find the second largest 'setsWon' value, and assign its 'rank' to 2, and so on.

I have attempted, but i receive a null pointer exception, and its because I am only able to assign a rank to the largest 'setsWon' Team, and not any others.

this is my attempt:

```
// create temporary team list
        ArrayList<Team> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        // teams is my ArrayList of 'Team'
        for (Team t : teams.getTeamList()){
            temp.add(t);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < teams.getTeamList().size(); i++){
            int max = 0;
            for (Team t : temp){
                if(t.getSetsWon() > max){
                    max = t.getSetsWon();
                }
            }
            if(temp.get(i).getSetsWon() == max){
                temp.get(i).setRank(i);
                temp.remove(i);

            }
        }
```

Team class:

```
public class Team {
    private String teamName;
    private ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int matchesPlayed;
    private int matchesWon;
    private int setsWon;
    private int rank;

    public Team(String teamName){
        this.teamName = teamName;

// these values are set to 0 for another purpose I have in my project
        this.matchesPlayed = 0;
        this.matchesWon = 0;
        this.setsWon = 0;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {

        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {

        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public void setPlayerList(ArrayList<Player> playerList) {
        this.playerList = playerList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayerList() {
        return playerList;
    }

    public void add (Player player){
        playerList.add(player);
    }

    public void setMatchesPlayed(int matchesPlayed) {
        this.matchesPlayed = matchesPlayed;
    }

    public int getMatchesPlayed() {
        return matchesPlayed;
    }

    public void setMatchesWon(int matchesWon) {
        this.matchesWon = matchesWon;
    }

    public int getMatchesWon() {
        return matchesWon;
    }

    public void setSetsWon(int setsWon) {
        this.setsWon = setsWon;
    }

    public int getSetsWon() {
        return setsWon;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return String.format("%s", teamName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the Team class?

Comment: What if the values of  `setsWon` for two teams are equal?

Comment: yes I will add the code for Team, and I haven't considered the case for if two teams are equal, i think for now you can assume they wont be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over your list to find out which team has the largest setsWon and then again to find the second largest and so on.. I would just simply sort the list (or a copy of it) by setsWon and use the index (or index + 1 as indices start by 0) as rank:

```
List<Team> teams = // your teams ..

List<Team> copy  = new ArrayList<>(teams);

copy.sort(new Comparator<Team>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
        return t2.setsWon - t1.setsWon;
    }        
});

for(Team x : teams){
    x.setRank(copy.indexOf(x)+1); 
}
```

You can of course sort your original list instead of making a copy if order dose not matter in your original list

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing to be careful of with Sorting - as a rule of thumb you want a Comparison method that is stable.. i.e. it always results in the comparison of two objects giving the same ordering (regardless of which object is compared first).

This comparator is un-stable - because it gives the same result when setsWon is the same on both objects.  But that means if t1 is first, then when sorted it'll stay first, and t2 will stay second.  BUT if you had a different input order for the sort the end result could be different (so different Teams appear in different orders - because setsWon may not uniquely provide an order).

```
new Comparator<Team>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
        return t2.setsWon - t1.setsWon;    // Whoooaaa I'm not safe !!
    }
}
```

THE general safe way to resolve this is to fall back to a secondary, or tertiary, or N'ary sort after that.
i.e.

```
new Comparator<Team>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
        final int comp = t2.setsWon - t1.setsWon;
        if (0 == comp) {
            return t1.teamName.compare(t2.teamName); // What if these are the same? [do again until only the same object gives 0]
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

For the purposes of this have ignored nulls - in production you need a strategy for them too (null.setsWon is probably not what you want).